# Prove $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell \iff \lim \inf a_n = \lim \sup a_n = \ell$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell \iff \lim \inf a_n = \lim \sup a_n = \ell$.

*Note: There are many proofs of this available.  My question is to verify* my *proof, and suggest improvements to its approach and writing.*

**Proof:**
(1) We first show that if $(a_n)$ converges, $\lim \inf a_n$ and $\lim \sup a_n$ exist. For any $(a_n)$, the sequence $(\inf \{a_n\})$ is increasing, by definition of $\inf$.
For any $(a_n)$ bounded above by $M$, the sequence $(\inf \{a_n\})$ is likewise bounded above by $M$.

If $(a_n)$ converges, it is bounded, and the sequence $(\inf \{a_n\})$ is bounded above and monotonically increasing. Hence, $\lim \inf a_n$ exists.  By a similar argument, $\lim \sup a_n$ exists.

(2) Since for any $k, \inf \, \{a_{n \geq k}\} \leq \sup \, \{a_{n \geq k}\}$, then $\lim \inf a_n \leq \lim \sup a_n$ (when they exist).

(3) If $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n > \ell - \epsilon$ for all $n \geq k$.  Thus, $\inf \, \{a_{n \geq k}\} \geq \ell - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.  Hence, $\lim \inf a_n \geq \ell$.  Similarly, $\lim \sup a_n \leq \ell$.  By (2), $\lim \inf a_n = \lim \sup a_n = \ell$.

(4) We now show the converse.  If $\lim \inf a_n = \lim \sup a_n = \ell$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $k$ such that $\ell - \epsilon \leq a_n \leq \ell + \epsilon$ for all $n \geq k$.  By the Squeeze Theorem, $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell$.

## Questions

1. Is the proof correct?
2. Are there any omissions? I'm aiming for rigor.
3. Is the exposition clear and organized? Could it be improved?
4. There were some gotchas where it's easy to incorrectly use $<$ instead of $\leq$. For example, in my point (3), it would not have been correct to write "Thus, $\inf \, \{a_{n \geq k}\} > \ell - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$."  Is that correct?

Comment: What do you call "the sequence $(\inf \{a_n\})$"? (I know it but you should write it.)

Comment: I would suggest being more clear in what your $\inf$s and $\sup$s are over (i.e. $\inf_{n\geq k} a_n$ for example)

Comment: Looks okay to me (expect for the $\inf$ sequence as pointed out in the previous comment).

Comment: Make explicit at the beginning  that $a_n\in\Bbb R$, and don't bother about the existence of limsup and liminf: they may be infinite but they always "exist", and when they coincide they are finite.

Comment: In (3), What do you mean by "Thus, inf{an≥k}≥ℓ−ϵ for all ϵ>0"?

Comment: @AnneBauval 1. I wasn't aware that you can compare limits of divergent sequences.   I thought the algebraic properties of limits only apply when they converge.  Can you clarify what we can and cannot do with divergent? 2. By "inf{an≥k}≥ℓ−ϵ for all ϵ>0" I mean for all $\epsilon > 0$, the $\inf$ of the set $\{a_n : n\geq k\}$ is $\geq \ell - \epsilon$.

Comment: 1. Limits of real sequences live in $[-\infty,+\infty]$ which is naturally ordered, hence they can be compared, nothing more mysterious. Note that a non-decreasing real sequence always has a limit in $(-\infty,+\infty]$ and a non-increasing real sequence always has a limit in $[-\infty,+\infty).$ 2. I suspected that, which is incorrect or at least not well written, because $k$ depends on $\epsilon.$